# Google kick Start 2020 Round A Allocation problem In java

Tags: java, code-completion, google-code

Anyone please help me out to solve this problem in java
As I have tried with following code

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Solution1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(System.out));
        long testCases = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        int n;
        long b;
        int[] a;
        int count;
        for (int i = 1; i <= testCases; i++) {
            String[] inputs = br.readLine().split(" ");
            n = Integer.parseInt(inputs[0]);
            a = new int[n];
            b = Integer.parseInt(inputs[1]);
            String[] input2 = br.readLine().split(" ");
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
                a[j] = Integer.parseInt(input2[j]);

            Arrays.sort(a);
            count = 0;

            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                b = b - a[j];
                if (b < 0) {
                    break;
                }
                count++;
            }
            bufferedWriter.write((String.format("Case #%d :%d", i, count)));
            bufferedWriter.newLine();
        }
        br.close();
        bufferedWriter.close();
    }

}
```

I have passed all test cases but whenever I submit my code, got sample failed: WA in resul....I dont know where I left something

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63591631/getting-sample-failed-in-google-kick-start-2020-round-a Please Check this out

Comment: It means you are getting wrong answer on sample test case.

Comment: yes exactly but I have cleared all sample test cases and there is no issue for anything. As Google is not specified what is wrong with my code  and which test cases not passed my code ....so can't figure it out that what is wrong with my code